# pl/sql : hitting a variable(different) partitions using query with different values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

a table contains 2 partitions
namely x,y

We have to query the table with variables which are not constant values and based on these varaibles the data must be fetched form x or y partitions

if Var =1 we have to hit x partition and if var=2 we have to hit y partition

Something like:

```
begin 
var :=&var

  delete  table partition(&var) where varaibles =some values

end;
```

i am getting an issue " illegal partition usage "

can we hit the partitions dynamically by substiting values

Comment: you want to drop a partition or just select from it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the partition name, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.

However, you should almost never need to explicitly specify the partition name.  Assuming your `WHERE` clause includes a predicate on whatever column the table is partitioned on, Oracle will automatically do the appropriate partition pruning so that it only has to hit the particular partition or partitions where the data exists.

Comment: @user1403174 - But, like I said, it would almost never be necessary/ appropriate to explicitly specify the name of the partition you want to hit in your query.  It would almost always be more appropriate to specify a predicate in your `WHERE` clause that allows Oracle to determine what partition(s) need to be scanned.

Comment: If the table is extremely very large...can we hit the partitions even though if the table has range partitions and we are hitting  the table with patitioned column values

Comment: @user1403174 - The whole point of partitioning is it makes it possible to efficiently access an extremely large table.  You simply specify a predicate on whatever column the table is partitioned on and Oracle figures out which partition(s) need to be hit.